# Kendo UI datepicker embedded in page

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, datepicker

I need to show Kendoui date picker embedded in the page, instead of popping it up on click of some input I need to show it when a container div (delayActionPanel) becomes visible.

Here is what I have tried, bit does not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

        $(".delay").click(function () {

            //Container Div
            $("#delayActionPanel").toggle("slide");

            //Target input-trying to perform a click using jq
            $('.k-select').trigger("click");
        });
    });
```

Comment: share your html also so we can answer better. by the way everything is embedded in the page, whatever you see on page.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle DEMO of your code?